Expectation of the Inverse of Sum of Weighted Identity Wishart Matrices
As noted in the title, suppose $A=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_ig_ig_i^T$ where $g_i\sim N(0,I_d)$ and $d < n$.
Essentially, $A$ is the weighted sum of $W_d(I_d,n)$. Ultimately, I want to calculate the expectation of $E[A^{-1}]$. I am able to reduce the problem to finding $E[tr(A^{-1})]$.
When I try to use the Stein Lemma trick to recovery $E[tr(A^{-1})]$, the $\lambda_i$ end up making that effort a dead-end.
So looking for ideas. Equivalently, finding out the distribution of the eigenvalues of $A$ as well.
